# Is Asp.net Core Websocket compatible with linux/docker?

Tags: c#, linux, docker, asp.net-core, websocket

I created an Asp.net Core 2.1 project with VS2017 and it is configured with a linux Docker container.

I would like to implement websockets, and so i followed exactly this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-2.1

If I set my ASP.net project as startup project (using IIS express), then everything works correctly, and I can connect to the websocket endpoint using the chrome [Smart Websocket Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smart-websocket-client/omalebghpgejjiaoknljcfmglgbpocdp) extension.

But If I set the Docker-compose project as startup project (so the app runs on linux container), then I get an exception on the server when I try to connect to the websocket endpoint.

Any idea of why this is working on IIS express but not on Docker linux container?

Here is the exception :

```
Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsServerAsync>b__51_1(IAsyncResult iar)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionAdapter.InnerOnConnectionAsync(ConnectionAdapterContext context)
HttpsConnectionAdapter:Debug: Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.

System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsServerAsync>b__51_1(IAsyncResult iar)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionAdapter.InnerOnConnectionAsync(ConnectionAdapterContext context)
```

**UPDATE 1 :**

Here are some more details on how I create my project :

In VS2017:

- File -> new project -> ASP.NET Core Web Application
- Select Core 2.1
- Select API
- Enable Docker Support with Linux OS
- Click OK

In Startup.cs in Configure(...) I add the following code :

```
var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions()
{
    KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
    ReceiveBufferSize = 4 * 1024
};
app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path == "/ws")
    {
        if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
            await Echo(context, webSocket);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }

});
```

In Startup.cs I add the following function

```
private async Task Echo(HttpContext context, WebSocket webSocket)
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
    WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
    while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
    {
        await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);

        result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
    }
    await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

- When I launch the app (iis express), the classic API is working using HTTP, same for Websocket.
- When I launch the docker version, the classic API is working using HTTP but not the websocket (error above is returned). -> another bug I have to investigate so.

I tried to activate SSL in project Debug properties :

- Then when I launch the app (iis express), the classic API is working using HTTPS, but the websocket hangs up (nothing is received on server side).
- And when I launch the docker version, the classic API is working using HTTPS but not the websocket (error above is returned).

Comment: The exception is showing an HTTPS connection failure, which is not closely tied to WebSocket yet. You might check if it has been reported to Microsoft yet, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues or post a new issue with more details there.

Comment: Hi @LexLi, I added more details in original post. I don't know why this was an HTTPS error as my project was not using SSL and I used the classic HTTP port in order to call the web api and the websocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just found what is happening.

Initial problem is that even if the project is not configured to use SSL (in Project->Properties->Debug->Enable SSL) the docker container will use HTTPs anyway. So you have to use the container's HTTPS port (viewable in docker-compose.override.yml) and also use wss:// instead of ws://

If you try to use the HTTP port, then the container app will try to redirect to HTTPS port. And this was what happened to me, causing the HTTPS error.

Regarding the "more details" section of my opening post, I did not use wss:// but ws:// and that's why the IIS Express app did not receive anything and Docker app was still displaying the error.